# How to define a tkinter variable as global?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to pull an integer from an `Entry`, and store it in a python variable to be used in various functions. Right now the problem I'm having is one of scope, wherein the `IntVar` is declared in one class, and the python variable is declared in another method in `class A` calls the IntVar to store it within a variable in `class A`.

Now I understand *why* the `IntVar` is not considered global. But when I try to put the `IntVar` anywhere *but* the class containing the gui, it returns an `__init__` error and quotes lines in the `tkinter` module.

I have also tried moving the functions to the UI class, but that gets ugly too because then I can't figure out how to call them from outside the `__init__` method, and putting them anywhere else causes a `NameError: name 'xxx' is not defined`.

Here's a quick and dirty mockup that illustrates the problem:

```
from tkinter import *

class SampleObj(object):
    def __init__(self, pyvar):
        self.pyvar = 0

    def SampleFunc(self):
        self.pyvar = tkvar.get()
        self.pyvar += 1
        tkvar.set(self.pyvar)

Test = SampleObj(0)

class MainGui:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("I'm a test Gui!")

        tkvar = IntVar()

        mFrame = Frame(master)
        mFrame.pack()

        self.Entry = Entry(mFrame, textvariable=tkvar)
        self.Entry.pack()

        self.Label = Label(mFrame, text=tkvar.get())
        self.Label.pack()

        tkvar.trace("w", Test.SampleFunc())

root  = Tk()
my_gui = MainGui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

As mentioned above, I've tried moving things around quite a bit, declaring the `IntVar` in places I think would widen its scope, but every time it's either "not defined" or an issue with the variable not being initialized within the root (I think that's what the other error means, anyway).

I've googled the heck of this for about four hours now, and found nothing that points to a solution. I also consulted someone else in person who I would consider intermediate in Python (compared to me as a novice), and they didn't know what to tell me other than that it was clearly an issue with scope (which I already knew). So, any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Tracebacks provided as requested.

Error for code as-is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "REDACTED", line 34, in <module>
my_gui = MainGui(root)
  File "REDACTED", line 30, in __init__
tkvar.trace("w", Test.Magic())
  File "REDACTED", line 8, in Magic
self.pyvar = tkvar.get()
NameError: name 'tkvar' is not defined
```

Error when I try to move `tkvar = IntVar()` up and outside of all classes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "REDACTED", line 3, in <module>
tkvar = IntVar()
  File "/home/redacted/apps/thonny/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py",   line 351, in __init__
Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "/home/redacted/apps/thonny/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 233, in __init__
self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
```

Comment: better add in question full error message (Traceback). BTW: to create global variable you have to create outside all functions and clases ie. `some_var = None`. If you create ie. `some_var = IntVar()` then you can use as argument in two classes and have access to the same value.

Comment: BTW: use lower case names for instances - `test = SampleObj(0)` and method `test.sample_func()` and Upper/CamelCase names only for class names.

Comment: BTW: `trace` expects function name - it means without `()` - `tkvar.trace("w", test.sample_func)`

Comment: To your first comment, @furas: I did try creating the variables outside of all classes. But it returned a different error. I'll add the traceback for that as suggest, though.

To the second: is there a particular reason to use lowercase instead of uppercase?

To the third: when I try using trace without the function's () it gives me an error saying that it was expecting a positional argument, so I had to put in () for it to work.

Comment: Second: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Third: when you use with `()` then python executes this function (at start of script) and assigns result to `trace` - but this function returns `None` so it assigns nothing in trace. `trace` executes function with three arguments so it has to be `def SampleFunc(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):` or shorter `def SampleFunc(self, *args):` - see [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Comment: probably you get last error because `tkvar = IntVar()` has to be use after `root  = Tk()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you try to do with this variables so I create example which only show how they can be used

```
import tkinter as tk


class SampleObj(object):

    def __init__(self, some_var):
        self.pyvar = some_var

    def sample_func(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        print(type(arg1), arg1)
        print(type(arg2), arg2)
        print(type(arg3), arg3)

        self.pyvar.set(self.pyvar.get()+1)

        print('global_var:', self.pyvar.get())


class MainGui:

    def __init__(self, master, some_object):
        self.master = master
        self.some_object = some_object

        self.master.title("I'm a test Gui!")

        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        tkvar = tk.IntVar(value=0)

        # use the same variable in entry and label
        self.entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=tkvar)
        self.entry.pack()

        # use the same variable in label
        self.label = tk.Label(frame, textvariable=tkvar)
        self.label.pack()

        # execute function when variable change value 
        # but it doesn't send new value to function
        tkvar.trace("w", self.some_object.sample_func)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# after tk.Tk()
global_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)

# use variable in class 
test = SampleObj(global_var)

MainGui(root, test)

root.mainloop()

print('END: global_var:', global_var.get())
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh! Okay! I see what you mean about where to place the global variable now. That does explain why none of the positioning I was trying worked. And you're completely right about the trace having the three arguments. I went to go look at the actual code where the real traces are, and I basically did it exactly as you have it. Slip of memory. I need to play around with this to see how to make it work for what I'm doing, but you have certainly pointed out the main flaw. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just before

> ```
>     tkvar = IntVar()
> ```
>
> use

```
global tkvar; tkvar = IntVar()
```

By mentioning global if its not in the global scope, it gets created.

Comment: Huh. I tried that, but my syntax was wrong. Even so, I have been given the impression by other StackOverflow questions that using global frequently is bad?

Comment: Hmm Ok. But that was your question . How to make it global :) !!